# dotnet core 2.2 layout page and components

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

I'm starting a new app using dotnetcore 2.2 and Razor pages.  I would like to 'componentize' the navbar portion of the layout file, to show the user name, and hide/show menu items based on who is logged in.  What is the best approach to take?  I tried partials, but couldn't seem to make it work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view component is a good option for what you're describing:

Default.cshtml:

```
@model NvarBarModel

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  // ...

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    // ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

NavBarViewComponent.cs

```
public class NavBarViewComponent() : ViewComponent
{
   public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
   {
     return View(new NavBarModel());
   }
}
```

And in your layout page:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("NavBar")
```

You can also invoke the component with a tag helper, but last I tried there was a bug (feature?) that required every parameter in the view component constructor be included in the helper or it simply didn't render.

[Here's a link to MS's documentation for view components.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm surprised VisualStudio doesn't make this a first-class citizen on the 'Add New Item' dialog (or maybe they do and I just haven't seen it)

Comment: No you're right @WOPR, it takes a little bit of manual setup for some reason.